# Minimum value of the expression ???

Tags: geometry

In an acute triangle ABC with usual conventions , $$k = \frac{\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{ 1}{r_2 }+\frac{1}{r_3}}{3},$$ where $r_1 $is excenter opposite to side A.
Find the min value of $$\sqrt{\frac{k6abc}{\delta}}=t,$$
where $\delta$ is the area of the triangle.

I simplified it and got $t=\frac{\sqrt{ (abc(a+b+c))}}{\delta}$

How to proceed??

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the reciprocal of the exradii is the reciprocal of the inradius, so $k=\frac{1}{3r}$ and 
$$ t = \sqrt{\frac{6kabc}{\Delta}} = \sqrt{\frac{2abc}{r\Delta}}=\sqrt{\frac{abc(a+b+c)}{\Delta^2}}=4\sqrt{\frac{abc}{(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)}} $$
by Heron's formula. Using Ravi's substitution $a=y+z,b=x+z,c=x+y$ we are left with the minimization of
$$ \frac{\frac{x+y}{2}\cdot\frac{x+z}{2}\cdot\frac{y+z}{2}}{xyz}\stackrel{\text{AM-GM}}{\geq} \frac{\sqrt{xy}\cdot\sqrt{xz}\cdot\sqrt{yz}}{xyz}=1$$
over $x,y,z>0$, which is attained by $x=y=z$ only, i.e. by the equilateral triangle.